# How to see if random number already exist in database?

Tags: php

I'd like my page to create a random number (numbers only). This needs to be a unique number. So, after the number is created, the code should check the database if this number doesn't already exist. If so, it should generate a new number and repeat the check. If the number's unique, the code can continue. What I have results in a page crash. What am I doing wrong?

```
$randomNR = mt_rand(10000,1000000000);

function newRandNR() {
    $randomNR = mt_rand(10000,1000000000);
}

function checkRandNR() {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE uid = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $randomNR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result(); 
    if ($stmt->num_rows != 0) {
        newRandNR();
    }
    $stmt->close();

}

checkRandNR();
```

Comment: Is the `uid` indexed? Not to mention, what you have here will not call `checkRandNR()` again.

Comment: OTOH, just make `uid` a unique column.

Comment: If you have a "crash", then take a look into the error log file. That is where you can _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: `$randomNR` does not exist in the scope of your `checkRandNR` function. You should pass it in as a parameter or just create it as a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers given, this is what I made, which works!

```
do {
$randomNR = mt_rand(10000,1000000000);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE uid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $randomNR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
} while ($stmt->num_rows != 0);
```

Comment: If you found any of the other answers "helpful" please upvote them.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in one of my projects to generate ID:

```
$id_exists = TRUE;
$uniqid = null;
do 
{
    $length = 10;
    $min = 1 . str_repeat(0, $length-1);
    $max = str_repeat(9, $length);

    $uniqid = date('Ymd') . mt_rand($min, $max); // YYYYMMDD0123456789

    $uniq_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE uid = ". $uniqid);
    if (!$uniq_id_check)
        $id_exists = FALSE;
}
while ($id_exists);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this Code:

```
function checkRandNR() {
    do{
        $randomNR = rand(10000, 1000000000);
        $exist = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE uid = '{$randomNR}'");
    }while(!$exist);
        return $code;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you need a prepared statement for this. Just cast the random number as an int and the query will be stable/secure.

```
function checkRandNR($mysqli, $randmNR) {
    if ($mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE uid = " . (int)$randmNR)->fetch_row()[0]) {
        // random number already exists.  Do what you wish.
        // newRandNR();
    } else {
        // you have a unique random number
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this single-serve "guess and check" scenario lends itself to iterated queries which should generally be avoided.

Perhaps it would be more advisable to send a batch of random numbers with `WHERE uid IN (...)` or something so that you are less likely to perform multiple trips to the database.

*I am passing your variables into the custom function scope as parameters because I like to discourage declaring globals.  Be sure to `return` something from your function.

Answer (score -1):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT MAX(*) as cnt FROM accounts")->execute;
$uid = $row ['cnt'] + 1;
```

Why you dont want to use AUTOINCREMENT field?